# Is there a way to establish a websocket connection in Flutter without the participants being in the same network?

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

Is there a way to establish a websocket connection in Flutter without the participants being in the same network? In best case without any external Server.

Are there libraries for this?

The Goal is to have 2 Smartphones that can communicate with each other (live), that aren't in the same nework.